# Thread-Limit ML4/COM started C# Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, com

I have two applications, the main-app is written in [ML4](http://www.ml-software.com/tech-ml4) (a programming language which compiles to machine language; I do not know much about this technology), the tool-app is written in C#.NET.

The main-app calls the .NET assembly via COM, invokes a delegate which does some work, shows a window, etc. So far it works pretty acceptable.

In the .NET app, I seem to have a pretty strict thread-limit. The complete application can have around 18 threads. Starting another one results in a `OutOfMemoryException` in `Thread.StartInternal` without any further information.

The question is obviously: why? Both apps run in the process of the ML4-app, but I never heard of such a thread-limit. Does maybe the COM-Interface cause it?

Or can a process be configured to have such limitation?

Typically, I wouldn't post such a question here, since it reads like a no-effort-question. The problem is, I have a very limited knowledge about processes and threads in the operating system, so I cannot really tell what possible causes could be.

Comment: There is no a thread limit, the app is running out of address space.  Probably because the host app gobbles up a lot of it.  Call the company and discuss your problem with them.